# Rear Rack for Cannondale Trail 6 with Disc brakes

Tags: disc-brake, rack

I was having a real trouble finding a suitable rear rack for my bike, a Cannondale Trail 6, with disc brakes.

My usual bike use is to the office (bag containing laptop, lunch, rain jacket, etc. with approx 7-8 kg. weight), but sometimes I do take my bike outdoors, which may or may not require a rear rack.

So, my expectations from the rack are:

1. Easy to remove them when not needed.
2. Something that goes in the rear wheel hub (in the quick release notch), not something attached to the frame.
3. To take on 12 kg. weight.
4. Easily installable and serviceable by me. :)

Please suggest some options. TIA.

Comment: There are, of course, the seatpost-mounted racks, but they have significant weight limits.  Any rack you find will want to attach to the frame near where the conventional brake mount would be, but that can probably be kluged to hook to the post.  There are adapter plates available (though can't tell you where) to allow conventional racks to attach via the rear axle (with an extra-long QR or some such).

Comment: Check out the [Tubus QR rack mount kit](http://www.thetouringstore.com/TUBUS/Fit%20Solutions/FIT%20SOLUTIONS%20PAGE.htm).

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. Unfortunately, Stack Exchange sites don't handle shopping recommendations very well. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ and http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/276/do-we-go-shopping

Comment: Appears to be a "shop for me" type question.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be the Blackburn EX-1 rack. I've used it on my cross bike due to it not having rack mounts and it carried my bike camping supplies quite well. It also comes with the long skewer. Also compared to a lot of racks it is fairly cheap.

Might not be quite as easy to remove/install if you don't have rack mounts.

[Blackburn EX-1 @ Nashbar](http://www.nashbar.com/bikes/Product_10053_10052_557875_-1___202601)

Answer (score 0):

You want an old man mountain Sherpa rack. It can be attached at the hub level and can be installed via hose clamps or fender mounts on rear seatstays.  It is made to even accommodate most disc brake equipped bikes.

http://www.oldmanmountain.com/

Comment: I was warned by the guy at a LBS that, in his opinion, mounting a rack to the QR is suicidal. The weight of the rack could detach the rear wheel from the frame when riding roughr terrain.

Comment: It seems like the intended use is for commuting, so I don't think its a big issue in this case. Certainly, you need to take extra caution with everything (including rear racks) for riding over rough terrain.

Answer (score 0):

Tubus logo is a great rear rack and I used it on my touring bike with magura louise disk brakes for around 13,000m. More information and my experience on my websites at [Cycle touring across Europe](http://www.weaveoftheride.com) [Caucasus to India](http://betweenworlds.bike)

The alternative would be to go for a seatpost mount or one of the other options mentioned here.